# FFmpeg : How to apply a filter on custom frames and place output of them between mainframes

Tags: windows, video, ffmpeg, blending

I have an interlaced video stream and need apply a filter (any filter that takes two frames as input , for example  tblend or lut2) on custom video frames and place output of them between mainframes like this :

```
 Input frames:  [1]             [2]             [3]  .....  FPS=25   
                 |  \         /  |  \         /  |
                 |   \       /   |   \       /   |
Output frames:  [1]   [f(1,2)]  [2]   [f(2,3)]  [3]  .....  FPS=50 i/p
```

I think I need `select filter + Expressions` to select frames, but I don't know how to do it

Please help.

**Note:**

```
Input has no audio stream.
Output = uncompressed yuv422 8bits in AVI container
the output scan type can be interlaced or progressive
I have to do this with just one command.
```

I tried `FFmpeg -i in.avi -vf tblend -vcodec rawvideo out.avi`, but the output of this command is not what I want.

Comment: What kind of filter is "like blend"?

Comment: @Rotem, Any filter that takes two frames as input , for example  tblend or lut2. (I edited the question)

Comment: Can you please edit your post with more details? What is the type of input file (is it MP4?). Is there an audio stream, or are you limiting your question to video? Please add FFmpeg command or commands to your post - without it answers may be completely off. (Also note that this is not a programing question and it is more suited for Super User site).

Comment: @Rotem, I edited the question, Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may chain `tblend`, `interleave` and `setpts` filters, while the two inputs to interleave filter are the output of `tblend` and the original video:

Example (assuming input framerate is 25Hz):

```
ffmpeg -y -i in.avi -filter_complex "[0:v]tblend=all_mode=average[v1],[v1][0:v]interleave,setpts=N/50/TB" -r 50 -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr24 out.avi
```

---

- `[0:v]tblend=all_mode=average[v1]` Creates a stream with `tblend` filter, and gives the output the temporary name `[v1]`.
- `[v1][0:v]interleave` applies [interleave](http://underpop.online.fr/f/ffmpeg/help/interleave_002c-ainterleave.htm.gz) filter of `[v1]` and the original video.
- `setpts=N/50/TB` fixes the timestamps to apply 50fps output video.
- `-r 50` sets the output frame rate to 50Hz.

Note: I selected `-pix_fmt bgr24`, because `yuv422` is not played with MPC-HC.

---

**Testing:**

- Build synthetic pattern (the `-r 25`, `rate=1` and `setpts=N/25/TB` are used for creating counting number at 25Hz):

  ```
   ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -r 25 -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1:duration=10 -vf setpts=N/25/TB -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr24 in.avi
  ```
- Execute the command:

  ```
   ffmpeg -y -i in.avi -filter_complex "[0:v]tblend=all_mode=average[v1],[v1][0:v]interleave,setpts=N/50/TB" -r 50 -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr24 out.avi
  ```
- Checking frame by frame:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the frames 0 and 2 are the original frames, and 1 and 3 are blended output of two original frames.

---

**Examples for two cases of interlaced video frames:**

[tinterlace](http://underpop.online.fr/f/ffmpeg/help/tinterlace.htm.gz) filter is used for creating **synthetic** interlaced video.

Simulating two fields that originated from a single video frame:

> 'drop_even, 1'
> Only output odd frames, even frames are dropped, generating a frame with unchanged height at half frame rate.

```
  ------> time
Input:
Frame 1         Frame 2         Frame 3         Frame 4
11111           22222           33333           44444
11111           22222           33333           44444
11111           22222           33333           44444
11111           22222           33333           44444
Output:
11111                           33333
11111                           33333
11111                           33333
11111                           33333

ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=2:duration=10 -vf tinterlace=drop_even,fieldorder=tff -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr24 in_drop_even.avi
```

[image]

Simulating two fields that captured at different times (not originated from the same video frame):

> 'interleave_top, 4'
> Interleave the upper field from odd frames with the lower field from even frames, generating a frame with unchanged height at half frame rate.

```
  ------> time
Input:
Frame 1         Frame 2         Frame 3         Frame 4
11111<-         22222           33333<-         44444
11111           22222<-         33333           44444<-
11111<-         22222           33333<-         44444
11111           22222<-         33333           44444<-
Output:
11111                           33333
22222                           44444
11111                           33333
22222                           44444

ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=2:duration=10 -vf tinterlace=interleave_top,fieldorder=tff -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr24 in_interleave_top.avi
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer +1 for your time, but unfortunately it is not what I want and your test is wrong, because the video you produced for the test is progressive not interlaced.

Comment: If you try an Interlaced source, you will realize your mistake.

Comment: I think it need a `Select` filter with an expression to select desired frames and fields

Comment: I have difficulty understanding what are the "desired frames and fields". Can you please edit your post, and add command line that creates an interlace source. Please edit your post so it be more clear what do you expect regarding the interlace subject. Does the 25FPS in your drawing actually applies 50 fields per second? What are `[1]` and `[2]`, 2 fields or 4 fields? Please also make it clear about the output (fields or frames?). You may add a new drawing showing even and odd fields.

Comment: as I wrote in the question, [1] and [2] are frame. Note: the input is interlaced,but the output scan type is not matter, so it can be interlaced / progressive.

Comment: "desired frames and fields", Sorry, I meant the frames or fields needed to do that

Comment: Sorry, but there is it still disambiguate and unclear. Each frame applies 2 fields (even and odd)? There are two options that (I think) I know: **1.** The two fields have the same timestamp (even and odd lines of the exact same frame). **2.** The two fields have different timestamps (the second field is captured 20msec after the first field). The first options looks simpler because converting to progressive scan is supposed to be trivial.

Comment: What do you mean "the frames **or** fields needed to do that"? Can you please update your post to make the interlace subject more clear. I don't want to post an answer based on wrong assumptions.

Comment: I think the question is clear, we have two interlaced frames and we want to put a blended frame between them, and it is certain that in the interlaced world each frame consists of two fields.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241716/discussion-between-rotem-and-maria).

Comment: I noticed that the first sample I tested with it was incorrectly captured as 1080i50 BFF while it should be TFF.  I tried another my interlaced video sample now it works, it was my mistake, I'm so sorry, thank you so much.